# Why do I receive this bird's paw buff sometimes?

Tags: elden-ring

Sometimes I just randomly receive this buff with a bird’s paw icon for a short time. I assume it’s a discovery buff, just like from one of the consumables. Why do I get this buff? I noticed it happens in open-world locations.

[image: screenshot of the buff described above]

Here is a GIF with this buff randomly appearing:

[image: GIF with the buff randomly appearing]

Comment: Golden scarab talisman? https://eldenring.wiki.fextralife.com/Golden+Scarab

Comment: I get that sometimes too. I know I don't have the Golden Scarab (nor have I ever worn any of the different Scarabs I've found), and I haven't consumed a single Pickled Fowl Foot so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like the effect you gain from the **rune weather event**. I think it happens when you see **golden leaves falling** in an area. If you are in this area, you gain a buff that **increases the amount of runes** obtained. I see the gold leaves on your screenshot's background as well :)

Comment: This is the correct answer! I've recorded a video (see the edit in my post) and you can clearly see golden  leafs are around soon after I get the buff. Thank you!